# Python 3 print without parentheses

Tags: python, printing

The `print` used to be a statement in Python 2, but now it became a function that requires parenthesis in Python 3.

Is there anyway to suppress these parenthesis in Python 3? Maybe by re-defining the print function?

So, instead of

```
print ("Hello stack over flowers")
```

I could type:

```
print "Hello stack over flowers"
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this? Or are you just curious? It is generally not good practice to redefine keywords even if it *is* possible.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are people down voting this? I do not understand how it lies outside of SO guidelines.

Comment: You may be interested in [this SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214881/can-you-add-new-statements-to-pythons-syntax)

Comment: I am using Python 3. However, typing  `()` all the time is unnecessarily time consuming.

Comment: If this is your goal then I suggest looking for ways to cut-down on the number of print statements you have to write instead of trying to workaround coding standards. Is there a particular program you are writing that requires a lot of print statements? If so perhaps you should open a new question about that specific program.

Comment: Michael, you don't seem so kind. Did I do something wrong? I am asking an honest question even if sounds like a workaround coding standards for you. If it was so "standard" they wouldn't change it in Python 3, would they?

Comment: I suppose I should have said "language specifications" :) I apologize if anything I said came across as offensive. I am only trying to help you get the most out of SO.

Comment: A good reason for this question is the gargantuan amount of 2.x code snippets on the web that use embedded print "foo" statements instead of print("foo") statements.  If you copy/paste 2.x code snippets, it requires editing, commenting or refactoring, which is more time-consuming than typing a single extra character.

Comment: I don't understand why would anyone up-vote an answer to a different question. Unfortunately in the real world we are not always able to rewrite our entire project, and please don't offer me Python3 migration tools here - some project have to also be backward compatible. "Impossible" would also be a great answer - from a knowledgeable individual.

Comment: I agree with Michael. In general, there is so much time hemorrhage elsewhere, that having an issue with those two brakets is misplaced zeal. I still find this question useful, though, because I wanted to know if it's worth learning the old print syntax. This is in case it is still used in Py3 alongside the new print() for some reason. The same way you have f'...string...' and '...string...'.format() running alongside. Glad it isn't the case.

Answer (score 34):

Although you need a pair of parentheses to print in Python 3, you no longer need a space after `print`, because it's a function. So that's only a single extra character.

If you still find typing a single pair of parentheses to be "unnecessarily time-consuming," you can do `p = print` and save a few characters that way. Because you can bind new references to functions but not to keywords, you can only do this `print` shortcut in Python 3.

Python 2:

```
>>> p = print
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    p = print
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python 3:

```
>>> p = print
>>> p('hello')
hello
```

It'll make your code less readable, but you'll save those few characters every time you print something.

Comment: Thank you TigerhawkT3. Yes, this would save time, but like you said it'll make the code less readable.

Comment: @Tigerhawk This workaround is not compatible with IDE

Comment: @ChandraShekhar - What IDE? What are you talking about? There's no reason for this to be affected by the choice of IDE.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I tried the same in Eclipse where it failed to work

Comment: @ChandraShekhar - And is your Eclipse environment pointing to Python 2?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Its Python 3

Comment: @ChandraShekhar - And in what way is it "not compatible"? What happens when you try it?

Comment: freaking p3 pissed me off with such kind of "goodies". Thanks! now all my prints would be p's :)

Answer (score 16):

Using `print` without parentheses in Python 3 code is not a good idea. Nor is creating aliases, etc. If that's a deal breaker, use Python 2.

However, `print` without parentheses might be useful in the interactive shell. It's not really a matter of reducing the number of characters, but rather avoiding the need to press Shift twice every time you want to print something while you're debugging. [IPython](https://ipython.org/) lets you call functions without using parentheses if you start the line with a slash:

```
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jun 28 2018, 05:43:53)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: var = 'Hello world'

In [2]: /print var
Hello world
```

And if you turn on `autocall`, you won't even need to type the slash:

```
In [3]: %autocall
Automatic calling is: Smart

In [4]: print var
------> print(var)
Hello world
```

Comment: Using python 2 as an alternative, as suggested by the post, is soon no more possible.

Answer (score 11):

Use Autohotkey to make a macro. AHK is free and dead simple to install. [www.autohotkey.com](http://www.autohotkey.com)

You could assign the macro to, say, alt-p:

```
!p::send print(){Left}
```

That will make alt-p put out print() and move your cursor to inside the parens.

Or, even better, to *directly* solve your problem, you define an autoreplace and limit its scope to when the open file has the .py extension:

```
#IfWinActive .py            ;;; scope limiter
:b*:print ::print(){Left}   ;;; I forget what b* does. The rest should be clear 
#IfWinActive                ;;; remove the scope limitation
```

This is a guaranteed, painless, transparent solution.

Comment: `b` means "use backspace to delete `print`", `*` means no further ending character like `Space` needed to activate replace" (https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)

Answer (score 5):

No. That will always be a syntax error in Python 3. Consider using `2to3` to translate your code to Python 3

Comment: I am using Python 3. I just want to avoid typing parenthesis all the time. `shift` + `9` ..... then again `shift` + `0` is exhaustive.

Comment: Sorry that the function calls make the typing difficult for you. I'm a pretty crappy typist myself, so even though I don't have any physical disability I do what I can to minimize use of shifted keys.

Comment: Apparently, no one appreciate the simplicity of the UP arrow when using  bash 'history recall'.   It's simple.   The same way with `print`, it should be unencumbered by useless debugging techniques  such as a pair of parentheses.

Comment: There are arguments for that, which were extensively rehearsed before the introduction of Python 3. While the extra parentheses may be inconvenient for us poor typists, the flexibility offered by the ability to redefine `print` was felt to be worth it, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

You can use operator oveloading:

```
class Print:
    def __lt__(self, thing):
        print(thing)

p = Print()

p < 'hello'   #  ->  hello
```

Or if you like use `<<` like in c++ iostreams.

Comment: your a genius, thank you so much for this, I'm going to use this every time, this is good python best practice for readability thank you so much! :)

Comment: nadapez I would but I didn't post the question, @laura did :(
I gave you an upvote though ;)

Answer (score 4):

The AHK script is a great idea. Just for those interested I needed to change it a little bit to work for me:

```
SetTitleMatchMode,2         ;;; allows for a partial search 
#IfWinActive, .py           ;;; scope limiter to only python files
:b*:print ::print(){Left}   ;;; I forget what b* does
#IfWinActive                ;;; remove the scope limitation
```

Comment: `b` means "use backspace to delete `print`", `*` means no further ending character like `Space` needed to activate replace" (https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured out the regex to change these all in old Python2 example scripts. Otherwise use 2to3.py.

Try it out on Regexr.com, doesn't work in NP++(?):

```
find:     (?<=print)( ')(.*)(')
replace: ('$2')
```

for variables:

```
(?<=print)( )(.*)(\n)
('$2')\n
```

for label and variable:

```
(?<=print)( ')(.*)(',)(.*)(\n)
('$2',$4)\n
```

Comment: Here is a regex that works in NP++ `(?<=print)( ')(.*)(')` `\('$2'\)`

Comment: Thanks @Jack, needed to escape the parentheses (just in replace?).. good to know. Also, I found a semi-related trick that Py3 recognizes having a space between `print ('string')`, so that the printable can more easily be highlighted and then use many editors' auto-close to add the parentheses and then quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because the only way you could do it without parentheses is having it be a keyword, like in Python 2. You can't manually define a keyword, so no.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, print is a function, whereas it used to be a statement in previous versions. As @holdenweb suggested, use [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) to translate your code.

Answer (score 1):

I have configured vim to auto-add the parens around my debug def calls when I write the file. I use a simple watcher that auto-runs my updates when the timestamp changes. And I defined <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd>+<kbd>**p**</kbd> to delete them all. The only caveat is that I have to have them alone on a line, which I pretty much always do. I thought about trying to save and restore my previous search-highlight. And I did find a solution on Stack. But it looked a little too deep for now. Now I can finally get back to debugging Ruby-style with a quick `p<space><obj>`.

```vimscript
function! PyAddParensToDebugs()
  execute "normal! mZ"
  execute "%s/^\\(\\s*\\)\\(p\\|pe\\|pm\\|pp\\|e\\|ppe\\)\\( \\(.*\\)\\)\\{-}$/\\1\\2(\\4)/"
  execute "normal! `Z"
endfunction

autocmd BufWrite *.py silent! call PyAddParensToDebugs()

map <c-p> :g/^\\s*\\(p\\\|pe\\\|pm\\\|pp\\\|e\\\|ppe\\)\\( \\\|\(\\)/d<cr>
```

I use these Python defs to do my debug printing.

```python
def e():
    exit()
def pp(obj):
    pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).pprint(obj)
def ppe(obj):
    pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).pprint(obj)
    exit()
def p(obj):
    print(repr(obj))
def pe(obj):
    print(repr(obj))
    exit()
def pm():
    print("xxx")
```