# Can I bind python-2.7's `print` in python-3.x, allowing me to use `print` without parenthesis in python-3.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, syntax

I like python **2**'s `print "TEXT"` which does not use without parenthesis, compared to `print("TEXT")` in python **3**.

Can I keep the python 2 print around to use by binding it to something like `pr`?

I understand has been discussed in this thread, but this wasn't mentioned as one of the solutions:
[Python 3 print without parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122868/python-3-print-without-parenthesis)

(By the way, the issue for me is typing and escaping the brackets. The keys `(` and `)` harder to press than a space bar. Also, because my IDE puts them in automatically, I then need to move my cursor out of it.)

**EDIT: This is neither a duplicate of the question as indicated NOR am I asking how to use python-3.x's print without parenthesis.** Instead, I'm specifically asking if I can bind a python 2 function (presumably after importing it). If the answer is no, that is new information.

Comment: Easiest solution: Use python 2 :)

Comment: On a more serious note, short of changing python's [grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) you absolutely cannot remove those brackets. The language has been built to recognise and parse functions this way, there's just no way around it.

Comment: In python 2 `print` is a keyword that triggers a statement. It's not a value that you can assign to something.

Comment: The easiest way to avoid typing brackets is probably to configure a snippet in your IDE. For example you could type `pr`, then press Tab, and have it autocompleted to `print()`.

Comment: the question you're linking to is a good candidate to close as duplicate... I'm tempted.

Comment: It wasn't mentioned as a solution because no solution exists. You simply can't use `print` as a statement if the language doesn't support it.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard you just killed my joy :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If you enjoy wielding the hammer, I'll ping next time :-D

Comment: The `print()` function is more useful than the `print` statement, allowing for `sep`, `end` and `file` parameters. I would try to look passed its slight increase in verbosity for the sake of its virtues

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard don't worry, I'm fine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921948/change-name-of-dictionary-or-list-in-a-loop  :)

Comment: This is neither a duplicate of the question as indicated NOR am I asking how to use python-3.x's print without parenthesis. Instead, I'm specifically asking if I can bind python 2's "print" function (presumably after importing it) to another one, i.e. "pr". 

If the answer is no, that is new information. This has not been been answered. Instead, my question has been flagged as duplicate and multiple answers have been given to another question that wasn't asked.

Comment: First of all, python 2's `print` is not a function, it's a statement. And secondly, you can't "import" python 2 functions into python 3.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want you need to define your own keyword, but you can't do this as you can't define or redefine language keywords without rewriting a compiler/interpreter/etc.

Comment: As as in the question, I'm specifically asking if I can bind python-2.7's "print" function (presumably after importing it) to another one, i.e. "pr".