# Change name of dictionary or list in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

So I have something like this:

```
for j, key in zip(range(10), SomeNestedDictionary.keys()):
      dictionary1 = SomeNestedDictionary[key]
```

However here `dictionary1` , is always the same name. Instead I would like a way to have `dictionary_someNameDependentOnTheIndexOfTheLoop`, so that I will create 10 dictionaries with different names. How do I do this? How do I control the name of the dictionary?

Also, is there a way of doing something similar,but with a list? I.e. changing the name of the list to be created at each iteration of a loop?

Notice this questions is different from the one marked as duplicate. In that questions simple lists could have solved the problem, here they cannot.

Comment: I don't think that question has been answered satisfactorily

Comment: This is a different question

Comment: I disagree. You want to dynamically create names in your global scope. This is covered in the duplicate with exec (although generally *not* suggested; a `dict` is a way better approach, see the second answer). I think pinging will work here, @Jean-François Fabre, so he can also explain how this is a good duplicate target.

Comment: @Euler_Salter: I don't see how it doesn't answer:: in the link there are a lot of answers explaining how to create variables on the fly, or store in dictionaries. In your case, I would do a dictionary of dictionaries, not generated variables (this idea of generating variable names generally sucks when you want to use them)