# How to write Hello World program in Python

Tags: python

I having some problem with Python Hello World program. So, I follow the Python tutorial on the internet. I'm follow the tutorial to install the Python interpreter and created a python file named HelloWorld.py and it look like this:

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

But the Python interpreter show error when try to run it while the online compiler of the tutorial website didn't have any error! So, what wrong with my code?

**Edit:** Fixed.

Comment: You'll want to find a newer Python tutorial as well. If this tutorial has the Python 2 style `print` statements, then it's going to have a lot of other outdated nonsense and will just cause you more problems like this as you proceed.

Comment: Just for more information, you might want to check this: [Python 3 print without parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122868/python-3-print-without-parenthesis)