# i made a program which tells the location etc by entering the ip adress but i have to now this format is showing error, what should i do to correct it

Tags: python, json, api

```
import  os

import urllib2

import json

while True :

    ip= raw_input ("what's the ip :")

    url="http://ip-api.com/json/"

    response = urllib2.urlopen(url + ip)

    data = response.read()

    values = json.loads(data)

    print ("IP:" + values['query'])
    print ("city:" + values['city'])
    print ("ISP:" + values['isp'])
    print ("COUNTRY:" + values['country'])
    print ("region:" + values['region'])
    print ("time zone:" + values['timezone'])
```

what should i add instead of these 2 ?

```
print ("latitude:" + values['lat'])
print ("longitude:" + values['lon'])
break
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: Next time please remember to post the actual problem, not just the lines causing the problem.

Comment: Related  [Print Combining Strings and Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018992/print-combining-strings-and-numbers) change '+' to ','.  `print ('latitude:', values['lat'])`?

Answer (score -1):

```
$ curl http://ip-api.com/json/1.1.1.1
{"status":"success","country":"Australia","countryCode":"AU","region":"QLD","regionName":"Queensland","city":"South Brisbane","zip":"4101","lat":-27.4766,"lon":153.0166,"timezone":"Australia/Brisbane","isp":"Cloudflare, Inc","org":"APNIC and Cloudflare DNS Resolver project","as":"AS13335 Cloudflare, Inc.","query":"1.1.1.1"}
```

From this, we can see that `lat` and `lon` are numbers in the JSON, not strings:

```
"lat":-27.4766,"lon":153.0166
```

So Python is complaining, because you can't add a number to a string.

To make it work, either convert the number to a string first:

```
print ("latitude:" + str(values['lat']))
print ("longitude:" + str(values['lon']))
```

Or, for a more modern and readable solution, use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
print (f"latitude:{values['lat']}")
print (f"longitude:{values['lon']}")
```