# How to add a sentence before the the number/int PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here's the code i did:

```py
list = input("Enter the number: ")

p = print("Trailing zeroes = ")

print(p, list.count("0"))
```

Output:

```
Enter the number: 10000

Trailing zeroes = 

None 4
```

The output i wanted:

```
Enter the number: 10000

Trailing zeroes = 4
```

Comment: `p = "Trailing zeroes = "`, remove the `print`

Comment: `print("Trailing zeroes =", list.count("0"))`…?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print Combining Strings and Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018992/print-combining-strings-and-numbers)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Taking into account @OldBill 's comment & answer:**
I corrected the code so that it gives an answer taking into account both of Op's problem.
The counting of the trailing zero is @OldBill 's code and not mine.

With

```
list = input("Enter the number: ")

p = print("Trailing zeroes = ")

print(p, list.count("0"))
```

What you do is `p = print("Trailing zeroes = ")` which is not a value. That explains the `None`when you print `p`.
Plus your counting of trailing zero doesn't work, and count all zeroes.

To have your code working, either you should have

```
num = input('Enter number: ')

ntz = len(num)-len(num.rstrip('0'))

print(f'Your input has {ntz} trailing zeroes')
```

or

```
num = input('Enter number: ')

print('Your input has', len(num)-len(num.rstrip('0')),' trailing zeroes')
```

Comment: What output do you get for an input of 101000? Note that this value has 3 trailing zeroes

Comment: Thanks for the comment, didn't really take this in account. I edited to give a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

To count **trailing** zeroes you could do this:

```
num = input('Enter number: ')

ntz = len(s)-len(s.rstrip('0'))

print(f'Your input has {ntz} trailing zeroes')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working example of the code:

```
i = input("Enter the number: ")

p = "Trailing zeroes = " + str(i.count("0"))

print(p)
```

Output:

```
Enter the number: 1000
Trailing zeroes = 3
```

Comment: The question itself is "add sentence before number". So I think the essence of it is more pasting/concatenating strings and numbers AND not using `print` to store strings. Correct me if I worng @Meemoz

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this:

**NB1**:  the *input* is a `string` not a `list`.

**NB2**: This will count all zeroes - not just trailing – (*By @OldBill*)

```
text= input("Enter the number: ")

print("Trailing zeroes = ", text.count("0"))
```

Comment: @OldBill, thank you for this note, I'll update it.  However, the *OP* Question is about **How to add a sentence before the number?**