# Why doesn't this code work, and how should I do it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
hp_character = input("Who's your favorite Harry Potter Character? ")
print(len(hp_character) + " is the number of characters.")
```

AIs say that it should be valid for versions 3.8 and newer, but VS Code says that it is a TypeError. It should say something like "10 is the number of characters."

Comment: Read the error message, it's pretty clear about the problem.

Comment: I don't know the connotation of that message but please don't be rude. I'm pretty new to coding and just needs help sometimes. Thank you.

Comment: In friendlier language, when saying your code is producing an error, please include the full text of that error as formatted text as part of your question.

Comment: Since you're new, now is a good time to start practicing [how to debug your own code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Writing code is only one part of programming; knowing how to debug that code is essential because nobody writes perfect code in the first attempt. Reading and understanding error messages is an important part of debugging, because that's the interpreter telling you exactly what is wrong and where. Also, it's part of asking a good Stack Overflow question ([ask])

Comment: I apologize if I formatted my question & details the wrong way. Thank you!

Comment: To everyone who replied, thank you so much for understanding my lack of knowledge. I will continue to improve my programming as well as my use of Stackoverflow. You guys inspire me. ☺️

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print Combining Strings and Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018992/print-combining-strings-and-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type error, you need convert the len from int to string. See corrected code below:

```
hp_character = input("Who's your favorite Harry Potter Character? ")
print(str(len(hp_character)) + " is the number of characters.")
```

Comment: Or use an f-string: `print("{len(hp_character)} is the number of characters.")`.